# Install4j setOwnerAction doesn't seem to work on symlink

Tags: install4j, owner

I'm trying to use the "setOwnerAction" in install4j to set the owner:group on the contents of a directory.  The "recursive" checkbox is checked.  It works fine when the directory is NOT a symlink, but when the directory that I give *is* a symlink, the action doesn't seem to do anything.  The log, however, indicates success.

I believe (from reading the man page) that by default, "chown" does not recurse into symlinks without a specific option being passed ("-RH"), but there's no way to indicate that option within the gui for the action.  I obviously don't know if "setOwnerAction" is using "chown", so I'm not sure that's relevant, but it was a thought...

Any thoughts appreciated...

Comment: You're right, the action will not follow symlinks and there's no way to configure this. We will consider this for a future version. You can use a "Run executable" action to call chown with the desired parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  We started with "run executable" for chown, but we run on different platforms that take different options - the best way to make it "generic" was to use a wildcard, but the wildcard ("*") wasn't getting interpreted - it was being considered as a literal filename.  I've worked around the symlink problem with "readlink" and calling the action on the dereferenced link name, but it's really somewhat of a kludge.